# Spark write only to one hbase region server

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hbase, rdd

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

def bulkWriteToHBase(sparkSession: SparkSession, sparkContext: SparkContext, jobContext: Map[String, String], sinkTableName: String, outRDD: RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Put)]): Unit = {
val hConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
hConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", jobContext("hbase.zookeeper.quorum"))
hConf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", jobContext("zookeeper.znode.parent"))
hConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, sinkTableName)

val hJob = Job.getInstance(hConf)
hJob.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, sinkTableName)
hJob.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TableOutputFormat[ImmutableBytesWritable]]) 

outRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(hJob.getConfiguration())
}
```

what I have found by using this hbase bulk insertion is that, every time spark will only write into one single region server from hbase, which becomes the bottleneck.

however when I use almost the same approach but reading from hbase, it is using multiple executors to do parallel reading .

```
def bulkReadFromHBase(sparkSession: SparkSession, sparkContext: SparkContext, jobContext: Map[String, String], sourceTableName: String) = {
val hConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
hConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", jobContext("hbase.zookeeper.quorum"))
hConf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", jobContext("zookeeper.znode.parent"))
hConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, sourceTableName)

val inputRDD = sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(hConf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
inputRDD
}
```

> can anyone please explain why this could happen?   or maybe I have
>   used the wrong way for spark-hbase bulk I/O ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question : I have used the wrong way for spark-hbase bulk I/O ?

#### No your way is right, although, you need to pre-split regions before hand & create table with presplit regions.

for example  `create 'test_table', 'f1', SPLITS=> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']`

Above table occupies 9 regions..

design good rowkey with will starts with 1-9

you can use guava murmur hash like below.

```
import com.google.common.hash.HashCode;
import com.google.common.hash.HashFunction;
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;

/**
     * getMurmurHash.
     * 
     * @param content
     * @return HashCode
     */
    public static HashCode getMurmurHash(String content) {
        final HashFunction hf = Hashing.murmur3_128();
        final HashCode hc = hf.newHasher().putString(content, Charsets.UTF_8).hash();
        return hc;
    }

final long hash = getMurmur128Hash(Bytes.toString(yourrowkey as string)).asLong();
            final int prefix = Math.abs((int) hash % 9);
```

now append this prefix to your rowkey

> For example
>
> 1rowkey1 // will go in to first region
>    2rowkey2 // will go in to
>   second region
>    3rowkey3 // will go in to third region 
>   ... 
>   9rowkey9 //
>   will go in to ninth region

If you are doing pre-splitting, and want to manually manage region splits, you can also disable region splits, by setting hbase.hregion.max.filesize to a high number and setting the split policy to ConstantSizeRegionSplitPolicy. However, you should use a safeguard value of like 100GB, so that regions does not grow beyond a region server’s capabilities. You can consider disabling automated splitting and rely on the initial set of regions from pre-splitting for example, if you are using uniform hashes for your key prefixes, and ***you can ensure that the read/write load to each region as well as its size is uniform across the regions in the table***

1) please ensure that you can presplit the table before loading data in to hbase table                                                                                                                               2) Design good rowkey as Explained below using murmurhash or some other hashing technique. to ensure uniform distribution across the regions.
Also look at http://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-hbase-region-splitting-and-merging/

> Question : can anyone please explain why this could happen?

reason is quite obvious and simple ***HOT SPOTTING of data in to one specific reason becuase of poor rowkey for that table***...

***Consider a hashmap in java which has elements with hashcode 1234. then it will fill all the elements in one bucket isntit ? If hashmap elements are distributed across different good `hashcode` then it will put elements in different buckets. same is the case with hbase. here your hashcode is just like your rowkey...***

#### Further more,

> What happens if I already have a table and I want to split the regions
>   across...

The [`RegionSplitter`](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/RegionSplitter.html) class provides several utilities to help in the administration lifecycle for developers who choose to manually split regions instead of having HBase handle that automatically.

#### The most useful utilities are:

- Create a table with a specified number of pre-split regions
- Execute a rolling split of all regions on an existing table

Example :

```
$ hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RegionSplitter test_table HexStringSplit -c 10 -f f1
```

where -c 10, specifies the requested number of regions as 10, and -f specifies the column families you want in the table, separated by “:”. The tool will create a table named “test_table” with 10 regions:

```
13/01/18 18:49:32 DEBUG hbase.HRegionInfo: Current INFO from scan results = {NAME => 'test_table,,1358563771069.acc1ad1b7962564fc3a43e5907e8db33.', STARTKEY => '', ENDKEY => '19999999', ENCODED => acc1ad1b7962564fc3a43e5907e8db33,}
13/01/18 18:49:32 DEBUG hbase.HRegionInfo: Current INFO from scan results = {NAME => 'test_table,19999999,1358563771096.37ec12df6bd0078f5573565af415c91b.', STARTKEY => '19999999', ENDKEY => '33333332', ENCODED => 37ec12df6bd0078f5573565af415c91b,}
...
```

> ***as discussed in comment, you found that my final RDD right before writing into hbase only has 1 partition! which indicates that there
>   was only one executor holding the entire data... I am still trying to
>   find out why.***

Also, Check

> `spark.default.parallelism` defaults to the number of all cores on all
>   machines. The parallelize api has no parent RDD to determine the
>   number of partitions, so it uses the `spark.default.parallelism`.

***So You can increase partitions by repartitioning.***

#### NOTE : I observed that, In Mapreduce The number of partitions of the regions/input split  = number of mappers launched.. Similarly in your case it may be the same situation where data loaded in to one particular region thats why one executor lauched. please verify that as well

Comment: thanks for the answer, I found that my final RDD right before writing into hbase only has 1 partition! which indicates that there was only one executor holding the entire data... I am still trying to find out why. and in that case, pre-splitting won't even help since there is only one executor running and writing data into hbase.

Comment: yes That also should be taken care! check default parallelism property since you are not repartitioning. spark.default.parallelism defaults to the number of all cores on all machines. The parallelize api has no parent RDD to determine the number of partitions, so it uses the spark.default.parallelism.

Comment: I tried repartition right before the bulk write into hbase, and that worked, so now I see data been written into multiple regions at the same time. However I tried setting spark.default.parallelism=64 and that didn't do anything. So now I am trying to find where the data got collapsed into one partition. thanks for your help, that was very helpful.

Comment: great.. If you have already not vote,  please care to vote-up if you are okay! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Though you have not provided example data or enough explanation,this is mostly not due to your code or configuration.
It is happening so,due to non-optimal rowkey design.
The data you are writing is having keys(hbase rowkey) improperly structured(maybe monotonically increasing or something else).So, write to one of the regions is happening.You can prevent that thro' various ways(various recommended practices for rowkey design like salting,inverting,and other techniques).
For reference you can see http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#rowkey.design

In case,if you are wondering whether the write is done in parallel for all regions or one by one(not clear from question) look at this :
http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_bulk_load.

Comment: thanks for the help, I did find that my RDD ends up been into 1 partition somehow, through a series of dataframe operations...although I don't know which operation triggered the partitions to collapse into one. I did read from hbase into 64 partitions and I can prove that by looking at sparkUI stages.

Comment: Even if your rdd lies in one partition only of spark,it will write to different hbase regions based on the key structure.I think that you are asking why spark does not write to hbase in a parallel fashion(one or multiple regions,doesn't matter) using multiple executors.If so,let me know.

Comment: yes you are right. It is been written into multiple regions based on the region split keys, so it's just that there is only one executor who is writing out, which hurts the IO performance.